# Random number in 2D array

Tags: java, random, multidimensional-array

I want to make random number in 2d array.

```
int i= 100;

int j= 200;

a[i][j] // is the random value between [0,1].
```

My question is I want to fix `a[1][j], a[2][j], ... , a[20][j]= 0.4`

And `a[i][1],a[i][2], ... , a[i][30]=0.4`

For the rest are random between `[0,1]` except `0.4`
How can I do this?

Comment: Which part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has and hasn't worked? If you don't put in any effort, we won't either.

Comment: Just to clarify: the *first* 20 rows are `a[0][j], a[1][j], ... , a[19][j]= 0.4` - is that what you (really) wanted (same for those 30 columns). array indexes are zero-based.

Answer (score 2):

Its worth remembering the first array index is `0` not `1`

I would fill the matrix with random values and then use one or two loops to fill in the known values.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you want row 20 of your array to be filled with 0.4 and the same for column 30 of your array. This can be done using two simple for loops:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        a[20][i] = 0.4; //fills row 20 with 0.4

    for(int i=0; i<a[30].length; i++)
        a[i][30] = 0.4; //fills column 30 with 0.4
}
```

After that it's just a matter of filling the array with the random numbers with a simple check while you do it to not overwrite these. So for example:

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; i<a[i].length; j++){
            if(a[i][j] != 0.4)
                a[i][j] = //insert random number generator here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, sir! can you expain why you set i<a[3].length Sorry i don't understand it.

Comment: Sorry, that's a mistake. it shouldn't be 3 it should be 30. It's just a typo.

Answer (score -2):

just as Peter said go through the array with 2 For loops and Math.random() and set the fixed values after that.

(i was too slow...)

Comment: i can do only this : int i,j;
       for(i=0; i<100; i++ ){
            for(j=0; j<200; j++){
                    a[i][j]= (double) Math.random(); 
                                }   
       }  
Where i should set the fixed values ?

Comment: forget to mention that Math.random() doesnt include 1. so if u really need 1 to be in a slot you need to adjust it. (if 0.99999 is fine u can leave it like that)

Comment: i dont understand your question. look at Galipans code. the first part sets 0.4 in your requested zone [0][0] - [20][30]